# Nextjs13 Images from cloudinary not working in production

Tags: next.js, cloudinary, next-images

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVCDK.png)

When I used the  component of "next/image", I found that if the src was from cloudinary, it would not display correctly. I tried replacing  with the  component of "next-cloudinary", and it does display, but only if the src is from cloudinary, which obviously doesn't work in all cases. How to fix it?

next.config.js

```js
  images: {
    domains: [
      'res.cloudinary.com',
      'avatars.githubusercontent.com',
      'lh3.googleusercontent.com'
    ]
  }
```

Comment: hi @hongk_bb, what is "would not display correctly"? Is the image distorted with the wrong aspect ratio? Can you share the front-end code? And do you have the original image's URL?

Comment: Just a note, uploading the original file without any dimension resizing is always recommended. Once the asset is already in your Media Library account, you could use our on-the-fly transformation for the different dimensions you need (see [documentation here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformation_reference#overview)). For additional information, you [may checkout this site as well](https://spacejelly.dev/posts/how-to-programmatically-upload-images-to-cloudinary-in-react-next-js/).